# Why the popular name for Pandas 熊猫 consists of its words in inverse order 猫熊?

Tags: characters, learning

According to Pleco dictionary the popular name for Pandas is 熊猫, while the "original" name is 猫熊.

Its characters meaning order change from:

- popular: bear cat
- original: cat bear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Popular perspective : [“猫熊”变“熊猫”](http://tech.gmw.cn/newspaper/2014-11/17/content_102037974.htm)

> 抗日战争期间，在重庆举办了一次动物标本展览，正式对公众展出了“猫熊”这种动物的标本。当时人们写汉字的顺序还是从右到左，可是写“猫熊”时，却依了英文的书写顺序，从左到右了。结果，“猫熊”让观众念成了“熊猫”。这次展览，是熊猫首次在大众面前亮相，影响很大，“熊猫”之名也传播开了。

[ In 1940s, at an exhibition of panda specimen, the name of panda is written from left to right as `猫熊` in accordance with the English name. But at that time people were used to reading from right to left, so it was read as `熊猫`, and became popular little by little. ]

Another perspective : [談“熊貓”和“貓熊”](http://www.huayuqiao.org/articles/yaodehuai/yaodh08.htm)

> “熊貓”語源上可能還是出自“小熊貓”
>   大熊貓太像熊了 (熊頭、熊身、短尾), 小熊貓太像貓了 (貓頭、窄身、長尾)。因此小熊貓應該稱“熊貓”, 大熊貓應該稱“貓熊”才是！而早期熊貓、貓熊的混淆, 其源頭可能就是在於小熊貓！

[ `熊猫` might come from (be confused with) `小熊猫` (`lesser panda`/`red panda`). ]

Comment: Translations were helpful.